# Creating NDVI tiles from NAIP tiles in R Loop

Tags: r, ndvi, loop, naip

I have a folder with many 4 band NAIP .tif tiles, band 1 = Red, band 4 = NIR. In R I would like to create/calculate unsigned 8-bit NDVI images for each of the tiles in a folder. I would like to write an output raster that maintains the input file name with the text "_ndvi" added to the end of the original name.

Input:

```
"G:\temp\m_4208801_se_16_1_20100701.tif",
"G:\temp\m_4208801_ne_16_1_20100701.tif",
"G:\temp\m_4208801_nw_16_1_20100701.tif",
...
```

Output

```
"G:\temp\m_4208801_se_16_1_20100701_ndvi.tif",
"G:\temp\m_4208801_ne_16_1_20100701_ndvi.tif",
"G:\temp\m_4208801_nw_16_1_20100701_ndvi.tif",
…
```

Here is the R code I use to calculate NDVI for 1 of the tiles

"install.packages("RStoolbox")

```r
# load spatial packages
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(RColorBrewer)

# turn off factors
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

setwd("G:/temp")

# import naip tile
naip_4b <- stack("G:/temp/m_4208801_ne_16_1_20100701.tif")
                               
# convert data into rasterbrick for faster processing
naip_br <- brick(naip_4b)

# calculate NDVI using the red (band 1) and nir (band 4) bands
naip_ndvi <- ((naip_br[[4]] - naip_br[[1]]) / (naip_br[[4]] + naip_br[[1]])*100 + 100)


# Export your raster
writeRaster(x = naip_ndvi,
              filename="m_4208801_ne_16_1_20100701_ndvi.tif",
              format = "GTiff", # save as a tif
              datatype='INT1U') # save as a INTEGER rather than a float"
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this for *one* file? Do you know how to do loops in R? Have you any experience with the `raster` or `terra` packages? What have you tried already?